# Determine Uiwebview or just use ios's Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to determine user use application Uiwebview or just use ios Safari by using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

> You can determine whether a webpage is displaying in standalone mode using the `window.navigator.standalone` read-only Boolean JavaScript property.

So you should check `window.navigator.standalone` property:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  // standalone app ~ UIWebView
} else {
  // Safari
}
```